# HTML 5 Canvas draw image over other image

Tags: image, html, canvas

I have two images I want to draw on one canvas. The problem is that the first image I draw might take longer to load than the second one. Since the pictures are drawn on the onload event it could occur that the first image is drawn on top of the second picture.

This is not what I want, I always want the second image to be drawn on top of the first image. Any ideas?

Comment: I think some code will be needed in order to answer this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var imgSrcs = ['url1', 'url2']; // <- put image URLs here

var imgs = [];
var loaded = 0;
var loadCallback = function () {
    loaded++;
    if (loaded == imgSrcs.length) {
        // draw imgs in correct order
    }
};

for (var i = 0; i < imgSrcs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i] = new Image();
    imgs[i].addEventListener('load', loadCallback, false);
    imgs[i].src = imgSrcs[i];
}
```